# Native Source for java.awt.Robot

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to find the native implementations of Java Robot functions. I found the Windows implementation [here](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~ohair/openjdk7/jdk7-build-copyright/webrev/jdk/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Robot.cpp.html). Where can I find the mac and linux versions. I'm mainly trying to find out what it's doing to see how I can implement this functionality myself in C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so I did some digging around and found what I was looking for. These may not be the latest versions but the metadata is there.

- Linux: [awt_robot.c](http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/17994444)
- Mac: [CRobot.m](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~michaelm/7113349/jdk8/webrev.2/jdk/src/macosx/native/sun/awt/CRobot.m.html)
- Win: [awt_robot.cpp](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~ohair/openjdk7/jdk7-build-copyright/webrev/jdk/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Robot.cpp.html)

Comment: Thanks Dave, was having trouble finding the Mac OS X CRobot.m

Answer (score 1):

The [source code of this class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Robot.java) seems having no any native methods, probably calls are delegated somewhere else. In any case, OpenJDK seems a proper place to search as this is a complete project and not just part that is written in Java.