# Control the mouse and keyboard Golang?

Tags: go, mouse

How would one go about controlling retrieving/setting the position of the mouse and triggier keyboard events on the operating system/X11 level? This is similar to functionality found in  the [Robot class in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).

I understand there will most likely not be a cross platform solution, but how would one go about implementing this on Windows, Linux and Mac?

Comment: You probably want to start by looking for better documented C solutions and then wrapping them in cgo.

Comment: For X11 at least, there's no reason to use a C library. [XGB](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xgb) is a native implementation of the X client protocol.

Comment: Thanks for XGB. Will make the job easier. Going to use the native Robot source as an example for creating a golang library: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18429666/122904

Answer (score 16):

Please see [robotgo](https://github.com/go-vgo/robotgo), Golang Native cross-platform system automation

Comment: Well, this doesn't compile. event/goEvent.h file not found #174 https://github.com/go-vgo/robotgo/issues/174

Comment: works on windows 10 as of 2024/03/22. nice suggestion

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to tackle this.

The project that appears closest to what you describe is "[ui](https://github.com/andlabs/ui)"

The next level up would be to use [one of the go bindings](https://github.com/search?l=Go&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&q=SDL) that calls [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/), which might be easier.

Higher up the stack would be a toolkit like GTK, QT, FLTK, (or even X11 as BurntSushi5 mentioned, but I wouldn't recommend it.)  Just search github for the toolkit and select by language.

Answer (score 2):

[ncurses bind](https://code.google.com/p/goncurses/) - is the most lightweight solution I've found, all the others are parts of graphic or gaming engines

Comment: OP asked for setting/retreiving mouse positioning, I don't think this is possible with ncurses...?