# I am trying to figure out how to do a virtual key press

Tags: go

For example if they typed something in the console for the program it would act like they pressed the "a" key.
This is different from this [How to react to keypress events in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198193/)… because that is if some key is pressed then do something mine is if some key is pressed then virtually press another key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to react to keypress events in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198193/how-to-react-to-keypress-events-in-go)

Comment: This is different from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198193/how-to-react-to-keypress-events-in-go because that is if some key is pressed then do something mine is if some key is pressed then virtually press another key

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446184/control-the-mouse-and-keyboard-golang

Comment: You mean read and send key events?